# Angularjs: pause bootstrapping until resources loaded

Tags: angularjs

Can I somehow hold the bootstrapping of the app in the `.run` method?

```
angular.module('myApp', [...])
  .config(
    ...
  )
  .run(function(AppService) {
    pauseLoadingRestOfApp();             // 1
    AppService.loadSharedDataAsnyc()
      .then(function() {
        continueLoadingRestOfApp();      // 2
      });
  })
```

Motivation:

My controllers expects that certain shared application data exists.

When my users login I can make sure to load all shared data before sending them from the login controller to the application.

But, when the user returns with an authentication cookie already in place and wants to go to `/admin` which is controlled by the `AdminCtrl`, I want to hold up the loading of the controller/page until the shared app data is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there would be many angular-gurus wanting to answer this question, but no... :)

So, my somewhat hacky solution is:

in `app.js`:

```
if(needsToLoadAppData) {
  $rootScope.isLoading = true;

  AppManager.loadAppData()
    .then(function() {
      $rootScope.isLoading = false;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('appDataLoaded');
    });
}
```

in my "main" - controllers:

```
var init = function() {
  if($rootScope.isLoading) {
    $rootScope.$on('appDataLoaded', function() { initData(); });
  }
  else {
    initData();
  }
  // ... init stuff that's not in need of "appData"
};

var initData = funciton() {
  // .. init stuff in need of "appData"
};
```

Note that you could simply use `$scope` instead of `$rootScope` in the controllers.

...not the most beautiful way but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delay starting up angular if you detect the cookie, though you'll have to do it server side and inject something like this:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
```

You can fire this whenever you want and I would have it delayed until your shared data is ready. Here's the link on it: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: I am already using this technique to load some non-angular resources (models in plain js which are also shared with the node.js server). In that case it makes perfect sense to delay the bootstrap since the resources I want to load is "outside of" angular. But thats not the case in this question.